# How can I link a component's current to variable resistor value in LTSPice?

Tags: ltspice

In LTSpice I want to implement an LDR resistor which changes due to the current passing through an LED.

I want the current through the LED (D1) to vary LDR. I want to use the LED's current in an equation and link it to LDR's resistance (ohm).

How is that possible?

[image]

edit: [image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure. Just type this instead of the value:

`R=I(D1)*1000`

`1000` would be the scaling factor and is often needed because currents are usually in the milli-range while resistors are usually in the kilo-range. You can put more advanced expressions instead of a simple constant factor. Make sure you don't end up with negative resistances and such, it can be difficult to build such a circuit.

To display the resistance as a trace after a transient response simulation you can use Ohm's law: `R=U/I`. You have to know the name of the voltage nodes on each side of the resistor you want to "measure", then edit the trace name to `(V(node1)-V(node2))/I(R1)`. It will give you a unit of Ohms.

Comment: how about the units?

Comment: I want 0mA LED current  will give 160k and 20mA LED current will give around 10k OHM with a lineer change. But the unit became KVA. How could you formulate it?

Comment: @user16307 Where did the unit become KVA? If you input the equation I provided, it will give a resistance.

Comment: I want to plot LDR but when I add trace the formula you gave it shows the unit in KA. How can I plot LDR resistance?

Comment: Sorry let me put it again: When I(D1) is zero mA LDR should be 1Mohm and when I(D1) is 20mA LDR should be 10k.. Can you help me to formulate this in Ohms?

Comment: i think this works R=-I(D1)*50000000+1000000

Comment: @user16307 Ok, great. Well, I can't really teach you the most basic algebra so I hope you figure it out. :P

Answer (score 2):

For this specific span, the following should work for a linear span from 160k to 10k from 0 to 20mA:

160k-(I(D1)*7.5MEG) - I used the dialogue box to enter that directly. This yields a linear span across your range. Make sure your current does not exceed 21.33mA (or use other functions available to prevent the value becoming negative).

Using max(160k-(I(D1)*7.5MEG), 1k) should do it; take the highest of the calculated resistance or 1k.

For a 1Meg to 10k span, we simply change the span control: You are starting at \$1M\Omega\$ and to get to 10k; therefore we need to reduce by 990k, so \$\frac {990k\Omega} {20mA} \$ = \$4.95*10^{7}\$ yielding:

> REFDES = max(1MEG-(I(D1)*49.5MEG), 1k)

You could, alternatively, use PARAM statements but that is not as elegant.